# Bash SSH change CHMOD in all files with a specific name?

Tags: bash, ssh, chmod

I have multiple Joomla! sites. How to search and change CHMOD in all "configuration.php" files with bash SSH to 444 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
find /path -type f -name configuration.php -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

You can also pass more than one path to find: `find /path1 /path2 ...`

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines:

```
SERVERS="server1.example.com server2.example.com server3.example.com"

COMMAND_TO_RUN="find . -name configuration.php | xargs chmod 700"

for SERVER in "$SERVERS"
do
    ssh SERVER <<EOF
    "$COMMNAD_TO_RUN"
    EOF
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
find / -name "configuration.php" -exec chmod 444 {} \;
```

(I haven't tested the syntax.)